# proxy settings in google pubsub

Tags: python, proxy, google-cloud-pubsub

i'm using below sample code for connecting google pubsub from python script. My organization uses proxy to connect to internet. could you tell me how to configure proxy setting in google cloud? I tried setting HTTP_PROXY env variable but still it fails.

```
import json
from oauth2client.contrib.gce import AppAssertionCredentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build

credentials =          AppAssertionCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub')
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub', ' https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write' ,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' , 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.read']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path to json file', scopes=scopes)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
pubsub1 = build('pubsub', 'v1',http=http_auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using below command:

```
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http(proxy_info =     httplib2.ProxyInfo(httplib2.socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP_NO_TUNNEL, 'proxy url wihout     http://', 8080, proxy_user = '', proxy_pass = '') ))
```

instead of 
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())